# HttpContext is null in a hosted service in .NET Core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I developed a .NET Core web application.

That web application should periodically get information from some controller of the same web application. To accomplish it, I have created a class that implements IHostedService interface. Then, in Program.cs file, I added the service with:

```
services.AddHostedService<EventPollingService>()
```

By doing this, I realized that the hosted service is instantiated as a singleton object.

On the other hand, I pass `IHttpContextAccessor accessor` in the hosted service constructor to get it available using DI.

The problem is that, in order to call a controller in the same app, I need to pass an absolute URL, so in the hosted service constructor I am doing this:

```
_baseUrl = accessor.HttpContext?.Request.BaseUrl() ?? string.Empty;
```

The problem is that in this case HttpContext is null.

On the other hand, inside the hosted service I need to do some insertions into a database, so I think I will have similar problems getting the DbContext instance since it is added as scoped service.

How can I do this? Can you recommend another approach in case this one is not technically possible?

Comment: `HttpContext`'s are specific to a given HTTP request from a client, you will never have an instance of it that you can get in a hosted service. To handle DbContext, you should inject an `IServiceScopeFactory` in your hosted service class, use it to create a scope, and use that to get a DbContext instance. [Further reading here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service#rewrite-the-worker-class)

Comment: @Luke so, the only solution would be to set the base URL address in appsettings.json file. According to what I described, can you think about another way to accomplish this? From my web app, I need to periodically make API requests to the same server to get some needed information and store that in the database. I am using `RestRequest` to call the API and the specified endpoint cannot be, for example, "/", to call the API on the same server and port. Since the server and port could be determined from the same web server (IISEXPRESS in this case), I am wondering if there is a way to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Hosted services has no `HttpContext` because they do not directly receive HTTP requests. If you want to get the URLs that hosted service is running on, use the `ApplicationStarted` trigger in your hosted service to access the server features. The code below explains what i mean:

```
public class EventPollingService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServer _server;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;
    private ICollection<string> _urls;

    public EventPollingService(IServer server, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
    {
        _server = server;
        _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
        {
            _urls = _server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>()?.Addresses ?? null;
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```